# ASP.Net MVC Ajax Form send JSON instead of field values

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a little different view of the common views in my project. It's using `Ajax.StartForm` like the all others. But in this case I just want to send a JavaScript object parsed in JSON, and not the value of the fields of my form.

To illustrate, I have imagine this steps: On this form, when *submit* button was pressed, the default submit event would be intercepted and a JavaScript object would be created - gathering values from some custom widgets - to be sent to the Action. Then that object would be sent like `data: JSON.stringify(that_object)` like on `jQuery.ajax`.

The problem is that I don't want to use `jQuery.ajax`, I want to use MVC's `Ajax.StartForm` because of some functions and validations automatically activated by my application to it.

There's a way accomplish that behaviour?

If that was not possible, I'm afraid I will be forced to store that object parsed in JSON as a string in a hidden field in order to submit it.

**UPDATE:**

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class ProcessWizardViewModel
{
    public long ProcessId { get; set; }
    public List<long> ProcessIds { get; set; }
    public List<ProcessItemWizardViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ProcessWizardViewModel()
    {
        ProcessIds = new List<long>();
        Items = new List<ProcessItemWizardViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ProcessItemWizardViewModel
{
    public long Type { get; set; }
    public bool Dependence { get; set; }
    public long ProcessCultureId { get; set; }
    public ProcessItemWizardViewModel() { }
}
```

`ProcessIds` comes from a grid with checkbox selection and `Items` comes from a tree view with checkbox selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're posting to an MVC `ActionMethod` (of some sort), it makes more sense to just have it post as you normally would and let the model binder handle it.  Otherwise, as far as I know, you're only other option would be using `jQuery.ajax()`

**Updated from question updates**

If your controller has an action that has a signature like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(ProcessWizardViewModel model) { }
```

and your view has `@model ProcessWizardViewModel` the model binder will handle the values correctly.

Comment: Yes, it will but I can't. It's a view with two widgets and I have to combine their data in just one object in order to MVC to serialize into a View Model.

Comment: Can you post the controller and view model(s)?  There are other ways to handle it.

Comment: Just updated the question with the View Model. I don't know if the Controller is important here, there's anothing on it. Actually its receiving the object as a string and deserializing it.

Comment: The problem is that I want to get rid of that hidden, not just treat it with a binder. But I see that I can't do this. I have no hope anymore.. haha but your tip is nice, thank you anyway, dude.